# Error upgrading irqbalance: insserv rejected the script header

Tags: debian, apt

I was upgrading my debian 8 system when one package produces an error:

> apt-get upgrade
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Calculating upgrade... Done
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>
> 1 not fully installed or removed.
>
> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
>
> Setting up irqbalance (1.0.6-3+deb8u1) ...
>
> insserv: pushd() can not change to directory ▒8]▒▒Ybnj
>
> ▒#▒▒Y^▒%▒HX5▒:▒z▒M▒B7Hs2▒CYhf▒>]P▒']i!9▒,▒H|▒R ̧v,▒/▒▒▒Ƣ▒y▒▒sC▒▒I&z#▒d▒▒a▒▒▒▒)t▒1z▒C]\Ny,▒.▒123456789: No such file or directory
>
> update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
>
> dpkg: error processing package irqbalance (--configure):
>
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> irqbalance
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Maybe some file is damaged. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by reinstalling insserv

```
apt-get install --reinstall insserv
```